# Angular Material multiple custom icons causes black square icon

Tags: angular, svg, angular-material, icons

I am trying to use custom SVG icons with angular material and am running into a problem when I try to use multiple custom icons in the same area.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-anrtj6

As you can see one of the icons is just a black square. If you edit the HTML and remove the 'import_dark' button icon then the first icon ('delete') works. If you put the 'setting' icon first then the settings icon doesn't work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have some css class issue.
I renamed the class in second svg, cls-1 to cls3, cls-2 to cls-4, and it works. 
check here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-jacv8h